# Show dialog window of Internet settings

Tags: android, dialog

I want to show dialog box when Internet is offline, but i have an error when trying do this... my code is following...
Can you tell me what i am doing wrong ?

here is code how i check is internet enabled or not:

```
if (!isOnline())
    {
        showNoConnectionDialog(getApplicationContext());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this code is how i show the dialog box in my app:

```
public static void showNoConnectionDialog(Context ctx1) 
{
    final Context ctx = ctx1;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.no_connection);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.no_connection_title);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.settings_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            return;
        }
    });

    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
    {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            return;
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

public boolean isOnline() 
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: You cannot add your popup to application, try to send your activity's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me.

Replace this

```
if (!isOnline())
    {
        showNoConnectionDialog(getApplicationContext()); // Error is here...
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

with

```
if (!isOnline())
    {
        showNoConnectionDialog(this);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet connection is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Enjoy :)